# how to fetch specific row data dynamically in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

Developers, I am developing a School Management system I put many data in data base and i also able to fetch each data in table

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sr.</th>
                    <th>Pic</th>
                    <th>Registration Number</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Father Name</th>
                    <th>Class</th>
                    <th>CNIC</th>
                    <th>More</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php $q=mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM students WHERE class='Play Group'");
                    if ($r=mysqli_num_rows($q)>0 )?>
                        <?php while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($q)): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$r['students_id']?></td>
                    <td><img width="40" class="img img-circle" src="uploads/<?=$r['students_pic'];?>" alt=""></td>
                    <td>LSPS-10<?=$r['students_reg']?></td>
                    <td><?=$r['students_name']?></td>
                    <td><?=$r['fname']?></td>
                    <td><?=$r['class']?></td>
                    <td><?=$r['cnic']?></td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="label label-primary" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#modal-id">View</a>    
                             <div class="modal fade" id="modal-id">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Full Record</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                        <h1>Ok</h1>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                             </div>      
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endwhile ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

but i fetech some of columns of that data now i want to fetch the rest of the columns in the modal which created dynamically in other words i fetch half data in table columns and others data in table inside modal my problem is how to fetch the rest of column in modal parallel to the data means when someone trigger modal all the data of clicked id modal is fetched which is fetched already.

Comment: your question looks to be more html/javascript related (so i added the tags).. what modal javascript do you use?

Comment: I am not using any javascript modal i use predefine modal which emmet in sublime 3 so basically i just use a js link in my project and use predefined modals so now please tell me what query i use to fetch the records in modal body?